# Creating variables based on column names in Pandas row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list

Currently I'm trying to import several CSV's and with Pandas turn the column names into a variable based on the data in the row.

By using `for index, row in df.iterrows()` I can loop trough the rows, but want to avoid typing all the possible columns as variables by hand. Also aware of the fact that I can adress the columns by using `df.columns()` or even `df.columns.tolist()` --> but figured there must be an option for the following:

```
  ColumnName1, ColumnName2, ColumnName3 ....
1  Value1,       Value2,      Value3   ....
2  Value1,       Value2,      Value3   ....
```

Which I want to turn into (per row):

```
row1
ColumnName1 = Value1
ColumnName2 = Value2
ColumnName3 = Value3
...
#Process variables, continue
row2
ColumnName1 = Value1
ColumnName2 = Value2
ColumnName3 = Value3
...
```

I'm aware that in the above example the ColumnName1-3 will be overwritten, but that is intentionally because every row will have some data transformation and stored/processed somewhere else.

I was unable to Google/Stackoverflow the answer I was looking for.... but that might be the phrasing I've used.

Answer (score 0):

After some further digging, I found that using `globals()[ColumnName] = Value` in a loop provided the solution for me.